# Enable Gutenberg for Woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, block-editor, editor

Via a php snippet I have enabled Gutenberg for Woocommerce. Works perfect but sometimes when I want edit product, I get a white screen on some product pages. Any idea how this happen? (Could be a JS conflict?) I'm not sure or there is a better way to enable the Gutenberg editor for Woocommerce or this a little bit unstable tweak.

WP vers: 5.8.2

PHP ver: 7.4.26

````
   if($post_type == 'product'){
       $can_edit = true;
   }
   
   return $can_edit;
}
add_filter('use_block_editor_for_post_type', 'wplook_activate_gutenberg_products', 10, 2);```
````

Comment: Third party plugins are off topic here, so I would ask this in the WooCommerce support forum. That being said, if it's not enabled by default then it's likely for a reason.

Comment: For those who found it because they want to enabe the Gutenberg editor for WooCommerce product without coding: https://wordpress.org/plugins/blocks-product-editor-for-woocommerce/

Answer (score 0):

Open developer tools in the browser and check for errors in console.
To better understand the errors, set `define(SCRIPT_DEBUG, true)` in your wp-config.php. Remember to turn this option off when done with debugging, because it uses dev version of React and slows down page.
Install React Developers Tools and Redux DevTools (if needed) - available for Chrome & Firefox, possibly for other browsers as well, for thorough debugging.

Good luck!